# Spring bean wiring issues when jar build on different operating systems

Tags: java, spring

Trying to debug a problem we're experiencing and I am at a loss.

We have a non-web project that uses Spring and we're compiling it into an executable jar (only the Spring part should matter here). When we run the jar that is built on my local machine using maven, all of our spring beans wire up correctly. However, when i run the jar built by our Jenkins build server (also using maven), one of the beans does not get wired in properly. I've verified that both my machine and the build server are using the same version of java (not same build, as I am on windows and build server is on linux) and maven. They also should have the exact same source code when building (i have no local changes). I am running them both from my development machine.

I've remote debugged the execution of both the jars and am getting different behavior. Given the example code below, when i run the jar built locally, when the MyConfig#bar method is invoked and the value of MyConfig#foo is the Foo bean i expected. However, when i run the jar built on our build server, when MyConfig#bar is invoked, the value of MyConfig#foo is null (I didn't think this could happen w/o a Spring exception being thrown). In addition, the console logs an error saying there is a circular reference on the use of the bean "foo".

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Autowired
    Foo foo;

    @Bean
    public Bar bar() {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setFoo(this.foo);
        return bar;
    }
}
```

Other things i've seen is that the jar build on the build server is a different file size than the one built locally. However, when i uncompress the jar and inspect the differences, all class and resource files are exactly the same. The only difference is in the manifest files that state the time and machine that built the jar (which i believe has no affect on execution).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

**EDIT (in response to @Nambari)**

Also, to maybe shed some more light on this, we tried building the jar on a different build server with its own Jenkins (has never had this source code before) and it also had the same problem. We also built the jar on different developer machiens and each built jar performed as expected. To me this eliminates the thought that our build server doesn't have the proper source code. We have also cleaned all maven repositories on both scenarios.

**EDIT (in response to @Jaiwo99)**

Below is how we are instantiating our application context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.scan("my.package.to.scan");
    ctx.refresh();
    ctx.registerShutdownHook();

    ... snip ...
}
```

**EDIT (new information)**

We've build this now on two different RHEL servers using the oracle jdk for linux and those do not work. We've also built on ArchLinux using the oracle jdk for linux and that jar worked. The only difference we noticed between the two was the ordering of the files listed in the jar.

**EDIT (new information)**

Just tried on Ubuntu and the bean gets wired in properly.

**EDIT (new information)**

Just tried on clean RHEL6 install (same as our build server) and it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess some mess up with your local code base. Re-synch and try a build again.

Comment: how do you load the spring context?

Comment: @Nambari i forgot to mention that we also created a build job on another server running Jenkins that has never had this source code before and the jar built there exhibited the same issues. In addition, we have built the jar on different developer machines and each work as expected. I added this comment to the question

Comment: Are there any error or exceptions being logged when you run the one built by the build server?  Something about not being able to autowire?

Comment: @Jaiwo99 added context creation to question

Comment: @PatrickGrimard we have DEBUG logging on and there are no exceptions on startup. Only until we try to use the bean that should have been wired in do we get an assertion failed exception.

Comment: Can you show the log output?

Comment: Why do you think that order of files in the jar wouldn't make a difference in wiring?

Comment: @BobDalgleish correct me if i am wrong, but i believe spring scans everything first building up a representation of what beans are needed and by which classes and will create the beans prior to injecting them. And it handles dependency issues through the use of proxies. reality is probably more eloquent than that, but think that's the gist.

Comment: @PatrickGrimard I'm going to be cautious about doing so as a) i don't think there is any useful information in the logs and b) not sure how my company would appreciate it if i did so. If there is anything specific you would like to look for, i can check. But to be clear, there were no exceptions or warnings from Spring in the logs.

Comment: @loesak -- I was asking and your answer was informative. However, we are still talking about a jumble of technologies here, where one slight misstep can cause the jumble to fall apart. I had an issue yesterday where "it should have worked" because it worked the day before. Finally, I checked the classpath and it turned out that one test had a bit of extra magic that the other did not. Rebuilding the classpath fixed the problem.

Comment: I just started to see this exact same behavior... Spring is injecting null values to a dependency that should be required, and letting it happen rather then throw a runtime exception.

In my case, I can put a breakpoint in the class which is referring to the wired dependency (which is null), and if I use the debugger to do applicationContext.getBean(name), Spring returns the bean (thus it has been constructed and is registered by name in the spring context, yet was not injected)

I've tried this on Spring 4.0.6.RELEASE and 4.1.0.RELEASE with the same results

Comment: @Alex I was able to get around the problem, but I did not solve it. I have seen beans get wired in as null before, just never where it depended on which OS the source was built on. Even though i could not trace down as to why this happens, I've always found that when it happens, it's a symptom that the project is not architected/organized properly. If this is your case, that i would recommend taking a step back and make sure my configurations are property organized and then refactor if needed. This has always has fixed the problem for me. This is what i did here and it worked.